# batch file to delete folder with special name

Tags: regex, batch-file, cmd

I want to delete all the folders with only digit name.
So I write a batch file using regular expression:

```
@echo off

D:
cd D:\Install\Work

for /d %%i in (*|findstr "^[0-9]*$") do (
      rd /s /q %%i
)

echo [all the folders under work are deleted!]

pause
```

but it doesnt work. Where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f %%x IN (
 'dir /ad /b * ^|FINDSTR "^[0-9]*$" '
 ) DO ECHO %%x
```

`FOR /F` reads lines from a file/command output to the metavariable.

`for /d` simply applies dirnames to the metavariable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off

for /r D:\Install\Work %%d in (.) do (
  echo %%~nxd|findstr "^[0-9]*$" >nul && rd /s /q "%%~fd"
)
```

Note that this will delete all-digit folders even if they contain other folders with names not consisting of only digits!

- `%%~nxd`: remove enclosing double quotes from `%%d` (`~`) and expand name (`n`) and extension (`x`) only
- `>nul`: suppress output on STDOUT
- `%%~fd`: remove enclosing double quotes from `%%d` (`~`) and expand full path (`f`)

Comment: what means "%%~nxd" ">nul" "%%~fd" ?